# Terminology for complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology

Let $c=x+iy$ be a complex number (with $x\ne0, y\ne0$). Then $x-iy$ is the conjugate of this number. Is there any term (or use) for the number $-x+iy$?

Comment: Not that I know of. I don't think another such term would be useful, since $-x+iy$ is equal simply to $-(x-iy)$, i.e. the opposite of the conjugate...

Answer (score 2):

The term that comes to my mind would be $-\bar{z}$, where $z = a + bi$.

Comment: [You can find some information on how to typeset mathematics on this website here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

the negative conjugation of complex number $c$? I don't believe there is a specific term for this.

Comment: Thanks. I'll got with "negative conjugate".